# Which country has the cheapest top-end mountain bikes?

Tags: mountain-bike, price, racing

I'm living in Brazil where top-end mountain bikes are very expensive, due to high import tariffs. I'd like to know which country has the cheapest top-end mountain bikes? top-end would mean a bike which can handle a race and is light, not necessarily carbon-fiber.

Comment: Would you be willing to fetch it yourself? Because if you just try and import it, the same tariffs will apply to you, too...

Comment: The intention is for me to grab it myself, it's preferred either way so I can actually test the equipment for buying it.

Comment: Johan, I have the same question. I travel quite a bit, and would love to pick up a high-end Specialized Epic or Santa Cruz, if I can find one cheaper in another country. Did you ever find a good option for this?

Comment: Voting to close. The answer to this question is likely a subjective matter of opinion, and even objective data on prices will be subject to frequent change due to fluctuation in exchange rates, travel and shipping costs.

Answer (score 5):

The factories that make these bikes are mostly in China and Taiwan, I've been told (by my boss when I worked in a bicycle shop).

If you're going there, maybe you can find a nearby retail outlet.

Answer (score 2):

The Mexican top-end mountain bikes Alubike, have cheaper bikes than Trek, Specialized, Giant, etc ... you can get one for $500 USD approx.

Update: http://www.alubike.com.mx/

Note that Montaña = Mountain

Comment: Certainly from places like Performance Bike you can get respectable mountain bikes starting at around 500USD.  (Of course, you can also get a bike there for 7500USD.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that it may be that some countries, particularly in Europe, have subsidized prices for bicycles, or, at the very least, artificially low import tariffs.  (I don't personally know of any, however.)